# Jupyter notebook kernel does not want to interrupt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was running a cell in a Jupyter Notebook for a while and decided to interrupt. However, it still continues to run and I don't know how to proceed to have the thing interrupted...

Thanks for help

Comment: Complete guess: you're using a bare `except` and should at least use `except Exception`? Beyond that, I don't know how we can answer this.

Comment: @roganjosh I have no `try-except`in my cell , nope. I was wondering if restarting the kernel could solve the problem and most important, would save my variables'values

Comment: Restarting the kernel will lose all of your variables

Comment: It sounds like something has crashed. My advice would literally be to switch the system off and on again. But know that you will lose any data you had in memory. Outside of that, I don't know what else can be suggested

Comment: @roganjosh What is strange is that in the Anaconda prompt, there are `Kernel-interrupted`messages, with a code following

Comment: @roganjosh What can I prevent to avoid those kinds of situation ?

Comment: We don't know anything about what caused it in the first place. You haven't shared any code or any indication of what might have been the issue. Just that something is frozen.

Comment: @roganjosh Honestly, I don't think my code is bad (i.e. infinite loop or something like this). Maybe a drawback is that I concatenate pandas dataframes in a loop which is not a good idea... : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower

Comment: @roganjosh I waited and finally succeeded :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this happens, when you are on a GPU accelerated machine, where the Kernel is waiting for some GPU operation to be finished. I noticed this even on AWS instances.

The best thing you can do is just to wait. In the most cases it will recover and finish at some point. If it does not, at least it will tell you the kernel died after some minutes and you don´t have to copy paste your notebook, to back up your work. In rare cases, you have to kill your python process manually.